# Java int cannot be converted to boolean

Tags: java

**Sample Code**

```
public Student(int y){
    idNumber= new CODE(y);
}
public boolean CODE(){
    int studentID= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Student ID:"));
    if(idNumber.verifyID(id)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public CODE getIdNumber(){
    return idNumber.get();
}

public void setIdNumber(CODE idNumber) {
    this.idNumber= idNumber;
}
```

**Problem**

Below is the "Edit Function" that I am trying to code. It is meant to assign the new ID as the IdNumber but I am having problems with the converting part.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Student g = (Student)Database.getData();
            int a = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Student ID:"));
            g.setIdNumber(a);      

    }
```

*Error*

incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Code

Comment: Well, `a` is an `int`, but `setIdNumber` takes a `CODE`. Tried `g.setIdNumber(new CODE(a));`?

Comment: Aside from that, you apparently have a class CODE and a function (which is not its constructor) also called CODE.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @marstran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setIdNumber() on your Student class currently takes in a CODE object, but in your actionPerformed() method, you are passing in 'a' which is an int. Try using 'new CODE(a)' as the input to setIdNumber().